# How to use in Angular inside an arrow function an object property (deeper than 1st level) sent by input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, arrow-functions, angular-input

I'm using angular 7 and trying to do something in a child component : use the input property that can be at first level in the object or deeper.

My child component has this piece of code :

```
if (this.values.filter(obj => obj[this.matchPropertyName] === $event[i].id).length === 0) {
  ...
}
```

where this.matchPropertyName is my input (can be 'id', 'myProperty.id',...)

For a single level (obj.id) this code works. However, I need to use sometimes from a deeper level (obj.myProperty.id) and it doesn't work.
How can I achieve this ?

Let me know if it not clear enough.

I'm using angular 7 and typescript 3.2.4

Comment: a 'good' solution would be to normalize your data and make sure the id is always available at top level I'm afraid..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in solution but you can make use of a simple `split` and `reduce`. For example:

```js
const value = this.matchPropertyName.split('.').reduce((pre, curr) => pre[curr], obj);
```

would give the value for `obj.myProperty.id` when `this.matchPropertyName="myProperty.id"`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbr5ut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

So in your case, you could use it like:

```js
const theValue = this.matchPropertyName.split('.').reduce((pre, curr) => pre[curr], obj);
if (this.values.filter(obj => theValue === $event[i].id).length === 0) {
  ...
}
```

Final result by the OP:

```js
myEventListener($event) {
   if (this.values.filter(obj => this.resolveProperty(obj) === $event[i].id).length === 0) { 
      ... 
   }
}  
  
resolveProperty(obj) {
   return this.matchPropertyName.split('.').reduce((pre, curr) => pre[curr], obj);   
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your great help ! I've slighlty adapt your suggestion as 'obj ' is unknown in "theValue" expression as it comes from the arrow function this.values.filter.
                    => So I did 
`if (this.values.filter(obj => this.resolveProperty(obj) === $event[i].id).length === 0) {
...
}

resolveProperty(obj) {
    return this.matchPropertyName.split('.').reduce((pre, curr) => pre[curr], obj);
  }`

Comment: @pti_jul ah yes I got lost in the variable naming I guess :-) Glad you figured it out though

Comment: Indeed, I thought afterwards that the variable naming made confusion where I read your stackblitz (thanks for your time !). Thanks again, you helped me finish my JIRA ticket, was the last remaining thing :)

Comment: Haha nice, glad I could help! :-)